# Code-push check for update

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm trying to update my app with code-push. My code is as follows:

```
export default class codePushTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            updateAvailable: false,
            downloadingUpdate: null,
            installingUpdate: null,
            downloadProgress: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        codePush.checkForUpdate().then(update => {
            if (!update) {
                self.setState({updateAvailable: false})
            }else{
                self.setState({updateAvailable: true})
            }
        })
    }

    handleUpdate() {
        let self = this;
        const checkUpdateStatus = (status) => {
            switch (status) {
                case codePush.SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE:
                    self.setState({downloadingUpdate: true});
                    break;
                case codePush.SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE:
                    self.setState({installingUpdate: true, downloadingUpdate: false});
                    break;
                case codePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED:
                    self.setState({installingUpdate: false, downloadingUpdate: false, updateInstalled: true});
                    break;
            }
        };

        const downloadProgress = (downloadedBytes, totalBytes) => {
            self.setState({downloadProgress: (downloadedBytes / totalBytes) * 100})
        };

        codePush.sync({updateDialog: false, installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE}, checkUpdateStatus, downloadProgress)
    }

    renderButton(){
        if (this.state.updateAvailable){
            return (
                <View style={{marginTop: 40}}>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)}>
                        <Text>An update is available.</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            )
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome message. </Text>
                {this.renderButton()}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Thus, what I'm trying is to check if there is an update available in `componentDidMount` and if it is, then update the state and depending on that state show update button.

But the problem is, when I push the code, and it is the newest code in the app, it still shows the button `An update available`.

If I change the content of my app and sent it to the code-push server with `code-push release-react AppName ios`, the button shows again, that is good. 
If I click on it the new content is shown and the button disappears an that is good.

But the problem is if I refresh the app I get again the old content and the button is shown again. And if I click on it again, nothing happens.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component needs to be wrapped with codepush. I haven't seen it in the docs. 
[Here is the link.](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/docs/react-native.html#link-7)

Thus:

Instead of

```
export default Item;
```

it must be

```
let codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL };
MainApp = codePush(codePushOptions)(Item);
export default MainApp;
```